# Is it possible, change TV input source programmatically?

Tags: java, android, hdmi

I have a TV with two hdmi inputs source:

- In hdmi1 connected satellite receiver
- In hdmi2 connected android
  device

I'm looking for possibilities to control active hdmi TV input from android(switched between each other)

In the beginning I thought about control TV by IR port, but I didn't find cheap usb ir stick.
Now I think about HDMI CEC, but very little information about it.
I don't understand, Does CEC allow make it?
Maybe exists other ways?

**Сlarification:**
I have a android application, which can play media content by scheduler, and sometime app must will be able to change input source TV to other HDMI port, and change back later. Finally: I need control input source TV from Android device.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, I believe you're searching for an HDMI switch.

For example:

http://www.amazon.ca/HDE-3-Port-Switch-Switcher-Splitter/dp/B0081J9OX6/ref=sr_1_5?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1443376976&sr=1-5&keywords=hdmi+switch

They even sell some that you can control with a remote:

http://www.amazon.ca/HDE-5-Port-Switcher-Support-Adapter/dp/B00DVKRHMK/ref=sr_1_8?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1443376976&sr=1-8&keywords=hdmi+switch

Comment: It is interesting device, but it not help me.
I will try to describe in more detail:
I have a android application, which can play media content by scheduler, and sometime app must will be able to change input source TV to other HDMI port, and change back later.

Finally:
I need control input source TV from Android device.

Comment: Hi @GrigoriyBorozdin, Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: @GrigoriyBorozdin did you find any answer?

Comment: @GrigoriyBorozdin did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TvInputManager.
`List<TvInputInfo> inputs = tvInputManager.getTvInputList();`

You can get information about each Tv input by TvInputInfo object which you will recieve in inputs list.
Now you can change the passThroughInputs (HDMI,AV,COMPOSITE) by

`Uri inputInfoIdUri =TvContract.buildChannelUriForPassthroughInput(tvInput.getTvInputId());`
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);`
 `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
 `intent.setData(inputInfoIdUri);`
  `context.startActivity(intent);`